# Is there any possible ways to bring up ionic framework to be responsive for all devices?

Tags: ionic-framework

that is to mobile devices,tablets ,laptops, desktop and also to larger screens.

I have already done it in Bootstrap. But I want to know that. Is there any possibilities that I can implement the same responsiveness to Ionic Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic, has a similar grid system.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-50">.col.col-50</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-75">.col.col-75</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col col-75">.col.col-75</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>
```

This will display this:

[image]

You can check all the documentation on [their page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid).

Comment: In this <div class="row"> they have used <div class="row responsive-sm">,<div class="row responsive-lg">,<div class="row responsive-md">. But if i use lg this will be applicable only till tablet. I wanted to know if there is any possibility that I can make it responsive for laptop and also for desktop resolutions..!

Comment: Ionic is not made to display on Desktops.